# Why is java.net.SocksSocketImpl the default java.net.Socket implementation in Java?

Tags: java

The question is brief.  **Why is a SOCKS-aware socket implementation the default choice for the implementation of the abstract `java.net.Socket` class?**  Naïvely I'd expect `java.net.PlainSocketImpl`.

The background is a bit more complicated.

I'm trying to kill off [GLASSFISH-12213](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-12213) (or really I'm trying to work around it).  The details of the bug itself aren't very important--there's a native library that is not thread safe, and some concurrent usages of it from a GlassFish-authored LDAP realm crash the JVM.

To work around it, I started working backwards: can I avoid having the native library called in the first place?  This led me for various reasons to look at [`sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java), which is in charge of [finding an appropriate proxy (or not) for a given URI](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java#DefaultProxySelector.select%28java.net.URI%29).  There's a [spot in there](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java#234) where it makes a native method call, and that is where the JVM crash occurs.  If I could avoid that call, I'd be in business.

One way I could avoid that call would be if I could ensure that the value of [`sun.net.spi.NetProperties.getBoolean("java.net.useSystemProxies")`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/NetProperties.java) false.  If that were the case, then the native method I mentioned earlier wouldn't be called.  `false` is the default and I haven't modified anything in this regard at all.

(So actually it *is* the case; demonstrably proven in the GlassFish instance running on that machine where I observed the bug.  I'm not sure how this code, therefore, could possibly still be loading the native library; that's a subject for another day.)

So, punting on that path, I backed up further: what protocol was being passed as the `URI` `scheme` in the `DefaultProxySelector.select(uri)` call?  Maybe I could then somehow influence the silly thing to still skip that native call somehow.

As it turns out, the protocol was `socket` (I had assumed it was probably something like `ldap`, but no).  This fact and my disproven assumption suggested to me that somewhere something in LDAP-realm-land was opening up a direct socket by hand (i.e. not using something like an `HttpUrlConnection` or some other abstraction).  Sure enough, the Sun-authored LDAP-JNDI bridge does just this; the URI that is passed in is `socket://somehost:389`.

So from all this **despite the fact I haven't set up any proxy information, configured anything or done anything other than use straight defaults**, it turns out that **the JDK attempts to use a SOCKS proxy.**  See [the `setImpl()` method in `java.net.Socket`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/Socket.java#Socket.setImpl%28%29) and [line 364 or so of `SocksSocketImpl.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/SocksSocketImpl.java#364) and trace it through for details.

(This finally suggests that I might be able to skip this whole codepath by simply adding a `socksNonProxyHosts=*` system property to the mix.  Jeez, shouldn't that behavior be the default?)

As a result--and again, taking it on faith that the `DefaultProxySelector` for some reason is having its [`hasSystemProxies` field set to `true`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java#90) despite no changes in configuration by me or GlassFish, **a garden variety socket created by a garden variety Sun LDAP connection is causing a native lookup for a SOCKS proxy server.  Maybe it's just me, but that strikes me as madness.**

So does anyone reading this--perhaps you are on the JDK team, or know someone who is, or know the history here--know why the default implementation of `java.net.Socket` always looks for a SOCKS proxy?

**Update:** I can see that the answer would be: so that if you have a system proxy set somewhere, and it's SOCKS-enabled, all stuff flows through it.  But if the default value of `java.net.useSystemProxies` is `false`, as it is, then what's the point of hunting (by default) for a SOCKS proxy?

Comment: Side note: I don't know why you think the JNDI LDAP driver should *use* the LDAP: protocol for its own communications. It is *implementing* the LDAP protocol itself, over a TCP socket.

Comment: Sure; I just naively assumed that it would implement the protocol inside a `URLConnection` somewhere (like `JarURLConnection` does for the `jar` protocol, if memory serves—it's quite possible it does not!).  I was just wrong  here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default socket implementation is `SocksSocketImpl` because the JRE **might** have been externally configured to use SOCKS via the system properties -D`socksProxyHost` and -D`socksProxyPort` or `ProxySelector.setDefault()` or via the default `ProxySelector` installed by the JRE.

`PlainSocketImpl` does **not** consult these properties or classes (because it is a plain socket and should not know anything about proxies) and so these external configurations would be **ignored** were not `SocksSocketImpl` always invoked to check on them.  I agree it seems odd that you get a `SocksSocketImpl` when nobody has said anything about SOCKS to the JRE, but I guess the architecture of `java.net.Socket` and `ProxySelector` does not allow it to preselect the correct impl at the time of Socket instantiation.

I think you (or whoever is leading the current line of investigation on that Glassfish bug) may be going about this the wrong way: rather than trying to subvert the way the JRE selects socket impls and proxies, why not fix the default `ProxySelector` and/or OS native calls so that when Java does its standard queries for information about proxies, things don't break.  I think the fix is in the guts of the proxy lookup process and classes, not higher up.

---

*Maybe another way to ask what I'm asking is: if `DefaultProxySelector` can tell me the proxies to use for a socket connection, why doesn't Socket invoke that first to help it pick a sane implementation?*

I think the problem is that `java.net.Socket` supports several programming models.  There's the obvious `new Socket(host, port)` constructor, but there's also a default constructor `new Socket()` which can be constructed first and then *at some arbitrary time in the future* can have its `connect(SocketAddress)` method called.

Since part of the criteria that a `ProxySelector` can use to determine whether a proxy should be used or not is the name of the remote host and remote port to be connected to (that is, the information supplied to `connect`), the `java.net.Socket` constructor is too early to know whether a proxy will be needed or not.

For whatever reason (can we just assume historical? / backwards compatibility reasons? :), the constructor for `java.net.Socket` the only place where the impl set, and, like I said, that is in some cases too early to tell whether a proxy will be needed or not.

Comment: I can appreciate that. The problem is I'm already configured everywhere (that is to say: not at all) for "please don't use system proxies anywhere" (the default JDK configuration). This direct socket opening by the LDAP machinery is the only one who seems to be subverting all of this.  To truly disable the usage of system proxies it appears you need `socksNonProxyHosts=*` as well which is counterintuitive to me.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Laird I think I may be missing some subtlety here.  It's still my opinion that the fix should be in the proxy lookup, so that the proxy selection process can be safely invoked and allowed to report *"thanks for asking me but -- nope, don't use a proxy."*  But, if you all are making progress in setting options to completely sidestep querying for proxy information, and are down to one last spot, then I guess it might be worthwhile to track down that last spot.  I'll have to reread your question and the bug trail to understand more fully.  Sorry if I jumped the gun.

Comment: No apology needed; I'm deep enough in this I need all the eyes I can get.  Maybe another way to ask what I'm asking is: if `DefaultProxySelector` can tell me the proxies to use for a socket connection, why doesn't `Socket` invoke that first to help it pick a sane implementation? Ignoring the GlassFish bug for a moment, that would allow it to use a simpler `SocketImpl` if no proxy information were forthcoming.

Comment: I responded in my answer since my response was too long for the comment box.

Comment: Beautiful; second to last paragraph gets the win.  Back to the GlassFish bug.

Comment: Thanks and good luck.  I'll read through the GlassFish bug more carefully and see if I can contribute an idea on a potential workaround or fix.

Comment: For posterity, I found the root issue behind the GlassFish bug; see https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18360?focusedCommentId=370414&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_370414

Comment: Alas, http://developers.slashdot.org/story/13/11/09/0016221/oracle-kills-commercial-support-for-glassfish-was-it-inevitable